# I want to validate the phone number in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to validate a phone number it should contain minimum of 7 digits.

```
const inputText = form.phone.value.trim();
  const pattern = /^\d{7}$/;
  if (!inputText.match(pattern)) {
    alert('Phone must be minimum of 7 digits.', 'error');
    return;
  }
```

The above code is what i tried. But it returns error if it exceeds more than 7 digits. it validates exactly 7 digits. And could anyone explains how these patterns are written.

Comment: You know what the `{7}` part means?

Comment: Dont know. I am a student.

Comment: Here's a hint: the regex validates exactly 7 digits. There is a `7` that appears in the middle of your regex. Do you think there might be a connection between the fact that the regex allows 7 digits and the fact that the number 7 appears in the regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[\d]{7,}`

This should do it. The {7,} means you need at least 7 characters.